# How to give a global a random number excluding 0

Tags: random, netlogo

I am quite new to Netlogo and I am experiencing the following problem. I want to give a variable a random number between 1 and 10, so without 0. Using the following code: `set random 10`, netlogo will also pick 0 as a possibility. Is there any way to avoid this? Random-float works, but this does not select whole numbers. Thanks in advance for any help!

Max

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I generate a number in the range between 0.3 < X < 0.7 with netlogo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805064/how-do-i-generate-a-number-in-the-range-between-0-3-x-0-7-with-netlogo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `random 10 + 1`. `random 10` generates a number from 0 to 9, adding 1 to it gives a range of 1 to 10.

Comment: Correct approach but actually needs `random 10` to get 0 to 9, and then add 1 to get 1 to 10.

Comment: Thanks guys! Was that simple indeed:)